# Android Listview clickable textview

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I have made an Listview populated with list_row_layout.xml(which is populated with json serializable class), i have clickable textview and onclick changing text from "Accept" to "Accepted". But when i click it on first listview item, another textview listview items below are changing. 
Here's some photos to descibe you better

[image: before clicking the accept textview]

[image: After clicking the fist accept textview]

this is the adapter class

```
   public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<FeedItem> listData;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> listData) {
            this.listData = listData;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                     convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.headlineView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sex);
                    holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.confid);
                    holder.approve = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.approveTV);



                     holder.approve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override

                 public void onClick(View argView)
                  {
                holder.approve.setText("Accepted");
               }
                    }
                );

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            FeedItem newsItem = (FeedItem) listData.get(position);
            holder.headlineView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getTitle()));
            holder.reportedDateView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getContent()));




            return convertView;
    }



    static class ViewHolder {
           TextView approve;
            TextView headlineView;
            TextView reportedDateView;
            ImageView imageView;

    }
   }
```

Comment: view recycling. change the data in the model, not in the view.

Comment: @njzk2 Is there any particular reason you added a comment that simply echoes the answer I had already given?

Comment: not really, didn't scroll down to your answer at the time. i mostly wrote that comment as a reminder in case i wanted to elaborate into an actual answer at some point

Answer (score 3):

Remember that views can be recycled via convertView.

In your onClick method you set the approve text to "Accepted" but when the view is recycled, you never set it back to "Accept"

Actually you need to update (something in) the list in response to an click and have the Accept/Accepted value toggle based on that value rather than simply updating what is currently visible on the screen.

-- to answer the "how" question (asked below)--

Add a new field to ViewHolder

```
static class ViewHolder {
        TextView approve;
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView reportedDateView;
        ImageView imageView;
        FeedItem newsItem;
}
```

Change the onClick method:

```
           public void onClick(View argView)
           {
              // note that holder no longer needs to be final in the parent class
              // because it is not used here.
              View parent = (View)argView.getParent();
              ViewHolder clickedHolder = (ViewHolder)parent.getTag();
              clickedHolder .newsItem.setAccepted(true);    /// a new method
              clickedHolder .approve.setText ("Accepted");
              Log.d(TAG, "Accepted item #" + position);
           }
```

After you have convertView created (if necessary)

```
        FeedItem newsItem = (FeedItem) listData.get(position);
        holder.newsItem = newsItem; // populate the new field.
        holder.headlineView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getTitle()));
        holder.reportedDateView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getContent()));
        if(newsItem.isAccepted ()){  // another new method!
           holder.approve.setText ("Accepted");
           Log.d(TAG, "Set text to Accepted for item #" + position);
        }else{
           holder.approve.setText("Accept");
           Log.d(TAG, "Set text to Accept for item #" + position);
        }
```

Once it is working you should consider removing the Log.d() lines to cut down on the noise in LogCat.

Comment: Can you please give me a example?

Comment: the textView isn't clickable, nothing happen when click on it

Comment: Add log messages to be sure you are reaching the onClick method.  I'll edit the answer to show those messages.   The results should appear in LogCat.

Comment: While I was editing to add the log messages I spotted another problem.   See the revised suggested solution above.

Comment: The method getTag() is undefined for the type ViewParent

Comment: Sorry I left out a cast.   I added a new line to make it clear(er):  View parent = (View)argView.getParent();

Comment: CustomListAdapter$1.onClick(CustomListAdapter.java:92)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)

Comment: clickedHolder.newsItem.setAccepted(true);   on this line